# Rewriting the floor function using inverse hyperbolic trig functions, instead of the sine function

Tags: trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Given that:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(2\pi kx)}}{k}$$

How can $\lfloor x \rfloor$ be rewritten using inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions ($\sinh^{-1}$, $\cosh^{-1}$, $\tanh^{-1}$) instead of the sine function? Additionally, is it possible to do so without using any other trigonometric functions (other than the inverse hyperbolic functions)?

Comment: no, because the fourier expansion for floor function is unique

Comment: $x-1/2+{\frac {i/2\ln  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi\,x}} \right) }{\pi}}-
{\frac {i/2\ln  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{-2\,i\pi\,x}} \right) }{\pi}}
$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk From a little preliminary testing, this appears to work perfectly. Can this formula be simplified if I intend to only floor real numbers?

Comment: @idempotence. Simplified-No,only for real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple:

```
restart:
func1 := x-1/2+(sum(sin(2*Pi*k*x)/k, k = 1 .. infinity, formal))/Pi;
func2 := evalc(Re(func1));
func3 := `assuming`([combine(func2, arctan, symbolic)], [x > 0]);
func4 := convert(func3, arctanh);
```

$$\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \tanh ^{-1}\left(-\frac{i \sin (2 \pi  x)}{\cos (2
   \pi  x)-1}\right)}{\pi }$$
Maple can't convert all for `arctan`.

Comment: Isn't this indeterminate for integers?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw .OP wanted it so he have.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more work we have for the fractional part $$\left\{{x}\right\} =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin \left({2\, \pi\, n}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2\, \pi} \left({\log \left({1 - {e}^{2\, \pi\, i x}}\right) - \log \left({1 - {e}^{- 2\, \pi\, i x}}\right)}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} arctan \left({\cot \left({\pi x}\right)}\right).$$

Then $\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor = x - \left\{{x}\right\}$.